# how to read 2 dimensional array with two delimiters

Tags: arrays, 2d, text-processing

I have to read in a file such as:

0,11,6,0,10x11,0,5,4,7x6,5,0,2,3x0,4,2,0,12x10,7,3,12,0

So I have to read this into a 2d array.

Here s my code:

```
    //set delimiter to commas
     String r1=",";
     String r2="x";
     input.useDelimiter(r2);
     //print file to check contents
     while(input.hasNext()){

         System.out.print(input.next());
     }

     //transfer file into matrix
     int[][] graph=new int[filelength][filelength];
     for (int row=0; row<graph.length;row++){
         for(int column=0; column<graph[row].length;column++){
             graph[row][column]=input.nextInt();
         }
     }

     }
    //close file
     input.close();
}
```

}

I had leave out the details of my code. But I m using a scanner class and I m trying to use two delimiters so that on the delimiter 'x' the code changes to another row of the matrix and on the delimiter "," the code inputs entry into the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, If you are okay with storing the data as a list of lists to make the 2d array then you can read in the file data, here represented as a string, and do the following:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> filedata = '0,11,6,0,10x11,0,5,4,7x6,5,0,2,3x0,4,2,0,12x10,7,3,12,0'
>>> array2d = [row.split(',') for row in filedata.split('x')]
>>> pprint(array2d)
[['0', '11', '6', '0', '10'],
 ['11', '0', '5', '4', '7'],
 ['6', '5', '0', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '4', '2', '0', '12'],
 ['10', '7', '3', '12', '0']]
>>> array2d[0]
['0', '11', '6', '0', '10']
>>> array2d[1]
['11', '0', '5', '4', '7']
>>> array2d[1][2]
'5'
>>>
```

If you want the actual integers you can do:

```
>>> arrayints = [[int(item) for item in row.split(',')] for row in filedata.split('x')]
>>> pprint(arrayints)
[[0, 11, 6, 0, 10],
 [11, 0, 5, 4, 7],
 [6, 5, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 4, 2, 0, 12],
 [10, 7, 3, 12, 0]]
>>> arrayints[1][2]
5
>>>
```